# How to mute everyone in a voice channel using discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have tried to overwrite permissions denying speak but it only applies when members leave and join the vc.
I have also tried "member.setMute(true)" but it mutes members globally, so they cant speak in any channel and I would like just to mute in one specific channel.

Comment: Please take a look at existing answers on StackOverflow and see if they answer your question. E.g. Your question is already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/q/55081354/5947203

Comment: @Ani I already saw that question, and that's why I said that I tried using member.setMute, but I need to mute the users just in one voice channel and not in the whole server.

Comment: consider going through similar answers again. For e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/62887805/5947203 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/55081354/5947203

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the following:

```
voiceChannel.members.forEach(m => {
            m.voice.setMute(1).catch(err =>{})
})
```

Here, it cycles through all the members in `voiceChannel` and server-mutes them. You can do `m.voice.setMute(0)` to unmute them. Additionally, if the command is being sent by a member that's in a specific voice channel, you can replace `voiceChannel` with `message.member.voice.channel`.

The catch is important in case it tries to mute someone who is already muted.